# regex html file href/src url pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, electron

Building an Electron app which gives you all colors of any website.

For that, the app downloads the url (like http://youtube.com) and saves it as html.
Now the app reads the html file and searches for any url which links to a file which might contain a color value (rgb/rgba/#/hsl), so those files would be css,js,svg etc. Those urls are added to an array, which is used by the electron-download-manager package lateron...

eg: `["href="/main.css?v=33.1"", "src="http://somesite.com/js/regex.js""]`

href=" / src=" are removed by other functions

My pattern for the url is:

```
/(href|src)=("|')(.*?)(\.|\/)(css|js|svg|json)(.*?)("|')/g
```

which just works fine, but it doesnt end matching on the closing quote symbol '/"

the match of the first example is the whole line, it contains everything after the closing quote, so the title="" is part of the url, which makes no sense

```
href="https://www.youtube.com/opensearch?locale=de_DE" title="YouTube"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" // matches everything until json is found

src="bla.css" // works
src='bla.css?ver=123.456' // works
```

Is there a regex rule which says "stop by this character"?

my rule should be:

> (start with href=", url , ends with .css/.js, optional fileversion(?v=123), quote symbol)

Comment: [Parse the HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead, then use something like `parsedDoc.querySelectorAll('link').forEach(...)` to get `href`s.

Comment: Where do you want to use the not operator? In regex ^ is a not operator you can use it like this `[^__]`

Answer (score 0):

A regex to find any tag with src or href attribute with value containing one of these
extensions or sub-dirs `css, js, svg, json` is this :

`/<[\w:]+(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\s(href|src)\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*?[.\/](?:css|js|svg|json)(?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*?)\s*\2))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>/`

https://regex101.com/r/tKrTSO/1

Where :

- Attribute is in group 1
- Value is in group 3

Expanded

```
 < [\w:]+               # Any tag

 (?=                    # Assert (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s 
      ( href | src )         # (1), href or src attribute
      \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (2), Quote
           \s* 

           (                      # (3 start), value
                (?:
                     (?! \2 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?

                [./]                   # One of these extensions or sub-dirs
                (?: css | js | svg | json )

                (?:
                     (?! \2 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
           )                      # (3 end)
           \s*               
           \2 
      )
 )
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```